# retrieve all rows over a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table in Sql server that contains Department Name, employee, and salary. I want to retrieve all employees in each department that have a salary in the first 10 values. Basically, do a partition on department name , order by salary and then get the 10th salary from the department and get everyone with a salary bigger or equal to the 10th one...
How do I do that?

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    * 
from (
    select 
        Department Name], [Employee], [Salary], 
        DepartmentSalaryRN = dense_rank() over(partition by [Department Name] order by [Salary] desc)
    from 
        [dbo].[TableName]
) t
where 
    DepartmentSalaryRN >= 10
order by
    [Department Name], DepartmentSalaryRN
```

Sounds like you want dense_rank(). If you want at most 10 employee's per department, use row_number().

Comment: this answers my question :). In the mean time my boss changed his mind, and he actually wants the order by row_number() get, the salary from row number 10 and get everyone who has a salary bigger than that...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the `TOP` statement. Try something like the below.

```
SELECT TOP 10 [Department Name], [Employee], [Salary]
FROM [dbo].[TableName]
WHERE [Department Name] = 'Name of Department'
ORDER BY [Salary] DESC
```

This retrieves information on the employees with the top 10 salaries in the given department.

Additional information on `TOP` can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx